# The 'TeX - LaTeX' favicon is incorrect in various places

Tags: bug

The favicon of the *[TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)* site uses the one for *[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour)*:

Hot questions list:

[image: Hot questions image]

Your communities list:

[image: Communities image]